# Inverse of a 3x3 matrix with 4 0's in the non diagonals

Tags: matrices

Hey how do I find an inverse for a matrix in the form \begin{bmatrix}a&0&b\\0&c&0\\d&0&e\end{bmatrix}
without having to use traditional methods, in the exam we are expected to know the shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Provided $c\ne0$ and $ae-bd\ne0$, the inverse is
$$\pmatrix{e/(ae-bd)&0&-b/(ae-bd)\cr 0&1/c&0\cr -d/(ae-bd)&0&a/(ae-bd)\cr}$$
The $c$ becomes $1/c$, the rest just looks like the short cut for the $2\times2$ case which I'm sure you know already.

Comment: It should be noted that the matrix is invertable iff the provided conditions hold.

Comment: Thankyou! My module is on regression so we only ever will be given invertable matrices in this form or similar for 4x4 with blocks of 4 0's, due to time constraints of exam :)